# no member named 'set' in 'std::vector<int>'

Tags: c++, vector

I use QT creator and Xcode 4.63 (osx mav)

I just call `.set(....)` and got following error

`no member named 'set' in 'std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >`

seem like something wrong with lib , since I'm new to QT creator i still got no idea how to make it right. (I'm new to c++)

```
#include <cctype>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "console.h"
#include "filelib.h"
#include "grid.h"
#include "gwindow.h"
#include "simpio.h"
#include "vector.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> myVector(10,0);

    fstream mystream;
    string getStream;

    while(getline(mystream,getStream))  {
        getline(mystream,getStream);
        if(stringToInteger(getStream)>=0 && stringToInteger(getStream)<=9) {
            myVector.set(0,(myVector[0]+1))
        };
    }
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: The error is quite clear.  That function does not exist. You'd have the same problem if you called `myVector.kerfluffle()`

Comment: The error is clear: `std::vector` has no method called `set`.

Comment: Side note: you've got unnecessary semicolons on closing braces `};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "set" method doesn't exist for vectors in STL. You could use the [] operator if you want to change a value:

```
myVector[0] = myVector[0] + 1;
```

or even

```
myVector[0]++;
```

Comment: `assign` is something different

Comment: ..based on your knowledge about what the poster tried to achieve using an non-existant function? :)

Comment: It doesnt matter, assign does something completely different that the code YOU posted